# Use local settings with Pycharm and Django

Tags: django, pycharm, django-settings

I'm using `Pycharm` in order to develop my `Django` project and I have a question with settings.

I have a **base.py** settings file which contains all settings (especially databases and emails settings) :

```
...

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'app_db',
        'USER': 'app_user',
        'PASSWORD': get_secret("DB_PWD", SECRETS),
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'test_app_db',
            'USER': 'app_user',
        }
    }
}

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'noreply@test.fr'
EMAIL_SENDER = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.test.fr'
EMAIL_PORT = 25

EMAIL_USER = ''
EMAIL_PASSWORD = ''

...
```

This configuration works on my distant server, but when I develop in localhost, I would like to take into account this same parameters in **local.py** file :

```
from .base import *
...

DATABASES['default']['USER'] = 'app_user2'

EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
...
```

My **wsgi.py** file looks like this :

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "main.settings.base")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And with Pycharm, I configured :

[image]

[image]

**Issue:**

My database parameter in local.py has been taken into account, but not my email `HOST` and `PORT` parameters.

==> If I define `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = main.settings.local`, it remains `smtp.test.fr` and not `localhost`. Same thing for email port.

How I can overwrite these parameters in local.py in order to not take base.py paramaters into account but parameters in local.py file ?

Comment: Does your configuration work fine with `./manage.py --settings=main.settings.local`?

Comment: Also how do you check `EMAIL_HOST` and `EMAIL_PORT` values? Looks like you import them directly from base.py. Can't imagine other reason why only mutable structure like DATABASES was changed but others did not.

Comment: @SergeiZherevchuk I can check `EMAIL_HOST` and `EMAIL_PORT` because with base.py, emails are sent by `smtp.test.fr` and receive on outlook while with local.py, I receive emails on maildev.